# Windows Phone 8.1 Cordova application scrolling not works after navigation

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm actually working on a Cordova single page application on Windows Phone plateform. And... I'm a kind of newbe on this... :o

Since the OS passed on 8.1 version I have problem with scroll when I navigate between two pages.

When I arrive on home page (lets pretend it's the first page that is loaded) I can scroll up and down without any problem.
But if I navigate from this page to an other one, the scroll does not works any more. Even if I navigate back, the scoll seems to be locked. I have to navigate once again to another page and navigate back to home to "unlock" the scroll.

First I thought the problem comes from the BouncyScrolling, so I tried to add this line

```
this.CordovaView.DisableBouncyScrolling = true;
```

in my MainPage.xaml.cs file, but that didn't fix the problem.

By the way, this problem only apears on 8.1 OS version. The scroll works great on 8.0 version.

If any of you have the solution, let me know. If you need more details, I'll do my best ! :)

Sorry for my bad english ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the lower version of jQueryMobile. Upgrading it solves the problem.